# How do I enable Nepumuk on Lubuntu? - "the nepomuk backup service does not seem to be running"

Tags: 12.04, backup, lubuntu

I want to start backing up my Lubuntu 12.04 machine (on an HP Netbook) using the built-in Nepomuk service. It was recently upgraded from 11.10 and I dimly remember having the same problem a few months ago, though I did not do anything about it.

Anyway: When I try to open Nepomuk Backup, I get the following error message: "the Nepomuk backup service does not seem to be running"

Now, I would like to enable Nepomuk, but I cannot find the switch. I have googled for this problem, but it only brings up Ubuntu answers ([like here](http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=1715)) with lots of packet talk that I do not understand.

So here is my question: **How do I enable Nepomuk?** And - by extension - how do enable it at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Nepomuk is a default Lubuntu app. It comes with KDE apps/system.

Did you at some point have a KDE app installed which you've then removed ?

```
$which nepomuk
$
$nepomuk
nepomuk: command not found
$
```

Comment: OMG, am I stupid. Thank you for pointing that out to me... Nepomuk does not come preinstalled on Lubuntu and apparently is incompatible with LXDE.

Comment: Not stupid :) I've done similar in the past.

Comment: You might want to try deja-dup

Comment: Cheers, found it meanwhile.